# Converting Slope Raster to vectors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have the attached raster inside ArcGIS. I want to convert this TIFF into a KML file. I figured I would convert it based on color to the point where i have a bunch of polygons that are the different slopes but I seem to be stuck.

So far I have tried to use the layer to kml tool and when I tried this option it created a 1kb .kml file which did not show any information. I also tried to vectorize by color but that also didnt seem to work

[image]

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you should use to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) slope to those 5 classes, [convert to polygons](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) *then* convert the polygon layer to KML